# Scrolling fix: a:hover + links in div not working any more because other div's margin is on top of that div

Tags: html, css, z-index

Recently I altered my site so that the divs below my jumbotron div (the first div after the nav bar)upon scrolling would go up, covering the jumbotron div. As cool as this is for an intermediate beginner like myself, I cannot click on the links on my jumbotron, nor does a:hover work.

I believe it is this way because the second div is on top of the first, I only use a margin-top of 660px on the second div to bring it down and expose the jumbotron.

Does anybody know a way to retain something like this way of scrolling while having the links on the jumbotron fully functional?

My html code: http://codeshare.io/L2eAF My css code: http://codeshare.io/jLiF3
Jsfiddle  https://jsfid dle.net/xksLsoat/

The page (blue on bottom is the second div):

Any help would be dearly appreciated!

[image: The home page]

Comment: Let me see this page in action, bcoz off missing css sources and other stuff...

Comment: Can you provide a codePen/jsFiddle or a link to the actual site?

Comment: k I will add that tomorrow as it is very late where I am

Comment: Added a jsfiddle - ignore the space in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, you set `z-index:-1` to #jumbotron so the div goes behind the #wrapper, no interaction possible ... just remove the z-index.

```
#jumbotron {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/WeLp8bN.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly the problem!